# C# HttpWebRequest shows 404, but site is reachable in browser

Tags: c#, xml, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-404

I am trying to download an xml file from a website with c#, but I get an 404 on some urls. this is wired because they still work in the browser. Other urls still work without a problem.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Timeout = 3000;
        request.UserAgent = "Test Client";
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)
                    request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("- "+response.StatusCode);

        XmlTextReader reader = XmlTextReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

This URL is one of the said problem URLs:

```
http://numerique.bibliotheque.toulouse.fr/cgi-bin/oaiserver?verb=ListMetadataFormats
```

SOLVED....forgot to trim the url ;)

Comment: Some servers verify User Agents. Try using a real one.

Comment: The server might be looking at the User-Agent header or other details about the request.

Comment: @Tom, your code works fine for me. Have you got other problem URIs?

Comment: @acoolaum, yes, there are several ones with this problem, @evan, it doesn't work with a real useragen either

Comment: here is another one, btw, it worked when i copied the first line ivo posted below, is there anything special with the @ in front of the string?
http://diglit.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/cgi-bindigioai.cgi?verb=ListMetadataFormats

Answer (score 3):

I can only speculate that the host site might not like your `UserAgent` and is returning a 404 message

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by using this:

```
var client = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
client.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
client.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
client.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";
var htmlCodae = client.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Answer (score 1):

For downloading xml document you can use DownloadString method:

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/4188449";

String xmlSource = client.DownloadString(url);

Console.WriteLine(xmlSource);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

1) Somehow you input incorrect url: can you try to 
   put

```
   WebRequest.Create(@"http://numerique.bibliotheque.toulouse.fr/cgi-bin/oaiserver?verb=ListMetadataFormats");
```

instead of

```
  WebRequest.Create(url);
```

for testing purpose.

2) You have some HTTP filtering mechanism which distinguishes between VS & browser requrests