# C# HttpRequest returning 404 error despite being browser-accessible

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently overseas and testing a vanilla HttpRequest that I know works outside of the country currently am in (Indonesia).

It seems when I try access a particular URL via a browser, it works perfectly. When I try replay exactly the same request via my C# program the same request returns a 404 response. . In fact, even when using a HTTP debugger that sniffs and replays the successful request, the 404 error will still occur.

Interestingly, when I try the browser request with Fiddler running, the browser then gets the 404 response which then seems to redirect to a "censorship" web-page.

Some points to note:

- There is nothing sensitive about the URL in question. All urls such as http://info.cern.ch/ seem to yield a 404.
- The link works perfectly when requested through a browser (except when Fiddler is running).
- The link is http, not https so there are no SSL certificates involved.
- I have tried matching the headers as noted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188449/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-shows-404-but-site-is-reachable-in-browser). In fact, as mentioned, if I replay the entire request via a HTTP debugger, I still get a 404 error despite the browser request succeeding.
- I have tried leaving the .Proxy property as-is and also setting to null but both do not work (I can see Proxy is automatically picking up some settings but not sure where from).
- The code is being executed under Winforms .NET Framework v4.6 like so:

  ```
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://info.cern.ch/");
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";
                request.Accept =
                    "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9";

                request.Proxy = null; // The request fails even if this line is commented
         response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
  ```

Does anyone know what would cause this behavior and how to ensure my C# application can access the URL and/or emulate the browser request?

Comment: Q: Exactly what class (e.g. HTTPClient) and library call are you using? Which version of .Net? What kind of app (ASP.Net Core MVC?  ASP.Net? .Net Winforms? Other?)  Please provide any additional details you think might be relevant.

Comment: Hi @paulsm4, thanks for your question. I've updated the question with more details including code snippet.

Comment: You're missing a quote at the end of `http://urlinquestion.com/file.bin`

Comment: Provide real url

Comment: Hi @NickFarsi, I've just discovered that it doesn't matter what URL I use. I just tried http://info.cern.ch/ with the same 404 result. This problem has something to do with the proxy being picked up or something similar. I have updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I built a little console app (Target framework=.Net 5.0, but it *shouldn't* make a difference, copied/pasted your code ... and I was *UNABLE* to reproduce the problem.

The problem does *NOT* appear to be "your code".  Nor the "UserAgent" header or  "Proxy" (either of which could potentially cause HTTP 404 errors).

**Sample code:**

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace TestHttpWebRequest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://info.cern.ch/");
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";
                request.Accept =
                    "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9";

                request.Proxy = null; // The request fails even if this line is commented
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                Console.WriteLine("response: StatusCode=" + response.StatusCode + ", StatusDescription=" + response.StatusDescription);
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample output**:

`response: StatusCode=OK, StatusDescription=OK`

**SUGGESTIONS:**

- Try `Accept: */*` (who knows - it might actually work!)
- Verify the problem is occurring on any arbitrary URL (e.g. "http://info.cern.ch/"), not just the host you were originally trying to connect to.
- Try moving your client to a different network (e.g. install the test app on your laptop, and try it out from a local Starbucks wifi).
- Analyze the traffic with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @paulsm4. It appears that the issue had something to do with the hotel proxy but I was unable to figure it out (I have since left). The code did work when I changed to another network which indicates somehow the routed requests seemed to know the difference between browser and app calls.  The problem was occurring on generic URLs.

Comment: OK: So it was definitely a "network" issue.  "Proxy" might not be the right thing to be looking at.  Wireshark probably would have told us a lot.  Anyway - since I doubt "successfully connecting from my hotel room" was a project requirement - it sounds like the issue is resolved.

Comment: I was trying to make sure the code worked on all networks. Some users had complained of seeing this problem but I wasn't able to reproduce it until that moment. Unfortunately I was unable to find the cause before I left, despite having tried a number of suggestions.